# Downloading files from server one by one - uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

In my application, i am offering non consumable in app purchase for selling Songs(Mp3) files.
Currently i am listing list of songs, when user taps buy, i am showing another uitableview (which is the view for Downloads screen ) with song name and Download button and Progress-view.

When user continues buy the songs, those songs will be added to the Downloading uitableview screen.
Where the user can download the files.

Currently i am able to download the files when tapping Download button and it shows the Download progress.So for it is working fine.

Now i would like to know , how do i start downloading the content from server without tapping a button.i mean when the first row of the uitableviewcell is completed downloading ,then the second row has to start downloading.

Please guide me , i am really cant find any suitable links / reference to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use recursivity and delegates, make the method you use to download things call its delegate which should call the download method again so the next item is downloaded. then keep doing this until all items are downloaded and activate a flag or something to stop the recursion.

Idea:

Right now you have a downloadmethod, this will download one song when the user pushes a button.

So instead of this make your DownloadMethod receive the song or whatever you want to download, It can be an array for example.

So now

```
DownloadMethod(arrayToDownload)
{
    If (arrayToDownload is not empty)
    { 
        [SongsArray addElement: download song in the last position with your original method]
        [arrayToDownload removeLastLemenet]
       downloadmethod(arrayToDownload)
    }
}
```

This is poorly done pseudocode but its the basic idea. Note that your operation has to be performed Synchronously for this to work without delegation. For your interface to not hang out you can make it be performed in a backgroundqueue for example (as long as the download is performed syncrhonously)

The synchronously thing just means to make sure every part of this code is performed after the previous one. But you do want to use grand central dispatch to perform all the code in another thread so your ui is not locked.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you please show me an example. as i am newb in this.please

Comment: the thing is that there is not just 1 way there are multiple, like using nsoperations for example... ill give you the basic idea, check the edit in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you implement your song download. Which thread are you using? Any download is lengthy and heavy operation and should be done on the non-UI thread.

From your description I would suggest for instance to create a subclass of `NSOperation` which would handle download of the song and use `NSOperationQueue` to process them.

With `NSOperationQueue` you can specify how many concurrent downloads are allowed (or unlimited by default). Each operation can then notify (or through a delegate) provide download progress.

1. User "Buys" a song by tapping button
2. Create `NSOperation` for the song's download
3. Add the operation in to the `NSOperationQueue` - set current controller as delegate or setup notifications